# Kibana Canvas - Any way to consolidate 2 metric elements into one markdown element?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an elastic sql query that returns 2 calculated ("last") columns. I have use 2 ["metric"](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-canvas-metric-and-markdown-elements) elements on a canvas dashboard to display the sum of each column, respectively (selecting "sum" of the column name in both elements under "Display -> Measure -> Number").

What I would really like to do is somehow incorporate both of these values in a "markdown" element that would contain both values, plus some text. After a lot of time spent playing in the expression editor and trying to understand the capability of this notation/syntax, I still can't figure out if this is possible.

All I have figured out so far is that with a markdown element, I can put the same query in under "Data" and put this under Display -> Markdown -> Markdown content

```
{{#each rows}}
 **{{column1}}** and **{{column2}}** 
{{/each}}
```

But in that scenario, only one row from the query result is used in reflecting the values of column1 and column2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use variables to incorporate the two results.